# Libreoffice: convert csv to ods and viceversa via shell

Tags: shell, csv, libreoffice, utf-16

This is my problem. A ".csv" file where delimiter is tab and content is a "Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text". If i try to open it with gui in libreoffice there are my successfully

[image]

if i'm trying via shell with

```
unoconv -f ods -e FilterOptions="9,34,UNICODE,1" [FILE]
```

the result is a file with no separation. What's wrong?

And what's is the best shell command in order to convert this ods to file to a well generated csv (Unicode UTF8, comma separated, ecc.)?

Comment: Hmm - the dialogue shows import filter options, but on your command line, you're using export filter options. Did you try to use import filter options (adapted to your csv) on the command line yet?

Comment: @tohuwawohu Ok, it works with `unoconv -f ods -i FilterOptions="9,34,76,1"` but now char à became �. I think it's an encoding matter. In gui "Unicode" is intepreted like UTF-16 in shell UTF-8.

Comment: Maybe using another tool to preprocess the csv and convert it to UTF-8 would be the easiest solution. Among the [Filter options](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Filter_Options), there's no UTF-16 Filter as far as i see...

Comment: @tohuwawohu this is my definitive solution
`iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8  /original/folder/file.csv > /tmp/file.csv;
unoconv -f ods -i FilterOptions=\"9,34,UNICODE,1\" ' /tmp/file.csv;
unoconv -f csv -o /original/folder/file.csv -i FilterOptions=\"9,34,UNICODE,1\"  /tmp/file.csv`

Comment: Just add the complete solution as answer - it's ok to answer your own questions if you've found a solution.

Answer (score 3):

this is my definitive solution

```
iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 /original/folder/file.csv > /tmp/file.csv
unoconv -f ods -i FilterOptions="9,34,UNICODE,1" /tmp/file.csv
unoconv -f csv -o /original/folder/file.csv -i FilterOptions="9,34,UNICODE,1" /tmp/file.ods
```